# Docker-compose with Gitlab CI

Tags: docker, docker-compose, continuous-integration, gitlab

I'd like to set up continuous integration with Gitlab. My application is set up through a number of docker containers, which are put together using docker-compose. My `.gitlab-ci.yml` looks like:

```
image: "docker/compose:1.25.0-rc2-debian"

before_script:
  - docker --version
  - docker info
  - docker-compose build
  - ./bin/start-docker

rspec:
  script:
    - bundle exec rspec

rubocop:
  script:
    - bundle exec rubocop
```

When I push, it tries to run `docker-compose build`, which in turn fails to find the docker daemon. This is not completely surprising, because I haven't tried to start the docker daemon. But I would usually do that with `systemctl start docker` - this fails because the runner doesn't use systemd.

How can I get docker-compose to build?

Some notes: `docker --version` and `docker-compose --version` indicate that both docker and docker-compose are installed correctly. If I try `docker info`, then I get the "cannot find docker daemon` error.

Answer (score 2):

`image: "docker/compose:1.25.0-rc2-debian"` indicates that you are running your pipeline on docker runner. Try running it on shell runner with docker and docker-compose installed and docker daemon running.

Other way would be to rewrite your docker-compose to .gitlab-ci.yml with proper dependencies.